# How is it possible for certain retailers to link Apple Pay transactions back to the original card that was used to make the payment?

Tags: security, privacy, apple-pay

From carrying out some research over the last several days, my understanding is that when adding a card to Apple Pay and when using the just-added card to make a transaction, the retailer only sees the specific Device Account Number (DAN) rather than the actual card number to increase privacy.

Within London in the United Kingdom, Transport for London operate the travel network throughout the region. If a card is added to Apple Pay and that same card is then added to a TFL account, it appears that it's then possible to view travel history if Apple Pay is used - see the below discussion threads on this subject:

https://www.reddit.com/r/london/comments/anpjw4/is_it_possible_to_register_apple_pay_contactless/

https://www.railforums.co.uk/threads/apple-pay-how-do-details-get-onto-your-tfl-account.123607/

So - my question. Since Apple Pay transactions are conducted by using the DAN rather than the actual number of the card used to make the payment, how is it possible for Transport for London to link Apple Pay transactions back to the originating card if the card number is never shared with retailers?